# Comando exec e system CentOs

Tags: php, ubuntu, centos

Galera, tento executar um kill, killall -9 para matar processo com o PHP e não funciona, será que tenho que habilitar algo dentro do php ?
Comandos mais simples como whoami pega...
OBS: Estou utilizando CentOs e Ubuntu.

```
<?php exec("killall -9 2119"); ?>
```

Comment: Creio que o problema está no fato de que `kill-all` precise de previlégios de `superuser`.

Comment: Otávio, no caso la quando eu logo no centOs, eu ja logo na conta como root, tem algo á fazer pra dar alguma permissão pra execução desses comandos ?

Comment: Nesse caso então deveria funcionar. Há alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: No php nenhuma, estranho que comandos básicos pega ..

Comment: Como você está executando esse script? Linha de comando? Ususário `root`?

Comment: toda vez que ele entrar no arquivo local ele deveria executar, no casa localhost/executar.php

Comment: Se você estiver utilizando apache então essa página executará pelo usuário `apache` que não tem previlégio suficiente para `killall`.

Comment: Se inglês não for um problema pra você dê uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580886/run-killall-command-in-php-shell-exec-function

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, de qualquer forma muito Obrigado Otávio!